# EOF Exception in a thread using sockets

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, eofexception

I have the code below:

```
while (true) 
{
lengthInput = instr.readByte();
// Other code
}
```

The thing is that I'm using a client to send information to the socket, but after it finishes I got EOF Exception and it brokes the thread, what I need is to manages this and dont stop the thread, because I need to send more information and be able to read it.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: EOF means that either client or server closed the socket. Could you check what happens after the client writes the data? What happens after the server reads the data?

Comment: After getting the EOFException, in the client I'm gettin ConnectionException: connection refused, and in the server the thread stops (Producer), I'm using a Producer-consumer model

Comment: @Arkady EOFException means that the *peer* closed the connection, or shut it down for output.

Comment: @OP Post the sending code.

Answer (score -1):

I guess the problem is related to your socket initialization. You probably need to check if your client socket indeed successfully create a socket and bind to a specified port. You may also check your client really send data to the outstream and flush to the server side. I have a small project on Android emulators with socket communication. Both my client and serve extends from Java Thread class. Maybe you can gain some idea seeing my code below.

### The client side

```
try {
        socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[]{10, 0, 2, 2}),
                Integer.parseInt(remote_port));//note we must keep the addr#10.0.2.2
        // write out
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        out.writeObject(out_msg);
        out.flush();
        // read in
        in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        socket.setSoTimeout(1000);
        in_msg.set_message((Message)in.readObject());
        // close all
        out.close();
        in.close();
        socket.close();
        return true;
    }catch(InterruptedIOException E){}
```

### The server side

```
while (true) {
            try {
                // read in message
                Socket ClientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                Message out_msg = new Message();
                // read in message
                ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(ClientSocket.getInputStream());
                Message in_msg = (Message) in.readObject();
                //Log.d(TAG, "recv" + " content:" + in_msg.msg2Str());
                message_process(in_msg, out_msg);
                // write out message
                ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(ClientSocket.getOutputStream());
                out.writeObject(out_msg);
                out.flush();
            } catch(Exception E){}
}
```

Comment: If the socket wasn't connected properly he would get a different exception, or wouldn't have a socket at all. If it was a flushing problem he would just block. He isn't using serialization. You don't need three closes, and your server doesn't have any so it leaks connections, There's nothing here that answers the question, or even addresses it.